# Using JSch to execute script on powershell

Tags: java, powershell, ssh, jsch

I want to execute powershell and then execute some commands on a remote windows system and I am using JSCH ( http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ ). I am having Win32-OpenSSH on windows machine https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH

When I use the "exec" channel it runs powershell and closes it off so I am unable to run commands in the powershell. On the other hand if I run "shell" channel I get output from command prompt such as "Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393] (c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. " So I want to execute the powershell and get the streams of the powershell process so I can write my script to that stream and read the output as well. The streams which I get by looking at the examples are the streams of SSH connection where powershell itself is run and not the streams inside/of the powershell.

I am using the following code to execute commands in powershell

```
private Streams executePowershell(Session session, String command) throws JSchException, IOException {
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    //4. Getting response as a stream

    channel.connect();
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();

    System.out.println(out);

    Streams streams = new Streams();
    streams.setInputStream(in);
    streams.setOutputStream(out);
    streams.setChannel(channel);
    return streams;
}
//command will be powershell to invoke the powershell itself
//command2 will be something such as dir that is the command to execute within powershell
public String executeCommand(String command, String command2) {
    String output = null;
    try {
        Session session = getSession();

        Streams streams = null;

        streams = executePowershell(session, command);

        OutputStream outputStream = streams.getOutputStream();
        Util.writeToStream(outputStream, command2);

        output = Util.readStream(streams.getInputStream()).toString();

        streams.getChannel().disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code from your program. Specifically, show how you're using jsch to invoke powershell.

Comment: ok, I have added the relevant source code.

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: Hey, were you able to find any solution to it?